# Function in PL/SQL to calculate distance from one city to all cities from a table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table with cities and their longitudes and latitudes. I need to write a function in PL/SQL to calculate all distances from one city to to all other cities in this table and return those distances. I have already made a function which computes the distance between 2 cities. I know that I need to work with a cursor. Any tips?

```
      `CREATE TABLE Rheinland_Staedte
      (Stadtname VARCHAR2(25),
      Noerdlicher_Grad NUMBER,
      Noerdliche_Minute NUMBER,
      oestlicher_Grad NUMBER,
      oestliche_Minute NUMBER,
       CONSTRAINT rhein_St UNIQUE (Stadtname,Noerdlicher_Grad,Noerdliche_Minute,oestlicher_Grad,oestliche_Minute)
      );


      INSERT INTO Rheinland_Staedte
      VALUES ('Aachen',50,47,6,5);
      INSERT INTO Rheinland_Staedte
      VALUES ('Bonn',50,44,7,6);
      INSERT INTO Rheinland_Staedte
      VALUES ('Düsseldorf',51,14,6,47);
      INSERT INTO Rheinland_Staedte
      VALUES ('Duisburg',51,25,6,4);
      INSERT INTO Rheinland_Staedte
      VALUES ('Essen',51,27,7,1);
      INSERT INTO Rheinland_Staedte
      VALUES ('Köln',50,56,6,57);
      INSERT INTO Rheinland_Staedte
      VALUES ('Krefeld',51,20,6,34);
      INSERT INTO Rheinland_Staedte
      VALUES ('Leverkusen',51,2,6,59);
      INSERT INTO Rheinland_Staedte
      VALUES ('Mönchengladbach',51,11,6,27);
      INSERT INTO Rheinland_Staedte
      VALUES ('Mülheim an der Ruhr',51,26,6,53);
      INSERT INTO Rheinland_Staedte
      VALUES ('Oberhausen',51,28,6,52);
      INSERT INTO Rheinland_Staedte
      VALUES ('Remscheid',51,11,7,12);
      INSERT INTO Rheinland_Staedte
      VALUES ('Solingen',51,10,7,5);
      INSERT INTO Rheinland_Staedte
      VALUES ('Wuppertal',51,16,7,13);

      create or replace PACKAGE GEOGRAPHICAL_PACKAGE IS


        FUNCTION DISTANCE(stadt1 VARCHAR2
                         ,stadt2 VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER ;

      END GEOGRAPHICAL_PACKAGE;
       /
      create or replace PACKAGE BODY GEOGRAPHICAL_PACKAGE IS

       FUNCTION DISTANCE(stadt1 VARCHAR2
                         ,stadt2 VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER  IS
        v_norgr Rheinland_Staedte.Noerdlicher_Grad%TYPE;
        v_nordmin Rheinland_Staedte.Noerdliche_Minute%TYPE;
        v_ostgr Rheinland_Staedte.oestlicher_Grad%TYPE;
        v_ostmin Rheinland_Staedte.oestliche_Minute%TYPE;
        v_norgr1 Rheinland_Staedte.Noerdlicher_Grad%TYPE;
        v_nordmin1 Rheinland_Staedte.Noerdliche_Minute%TYPE;
        v_ostgr1 Rheinland_Staedte.oestlicher_Grad%TYPE;
        v_ostmin1 Rheinland_Staedte.oestliche_Minute%TYPE;
        latitude_min NUMBER;
      longitude_min  NUMBER;
      latitude_min1 NUMBER;
      longitude_min1 NUMBER;
        distance  NUMBER;
      BEGIN
      SELECT Noerdlicher_Grad,Noerdliche_Minute,oestlicher_Grad,oestliche_Minute INTO v_norgr,v_nordmin,v_ostgr,v_ostmin FROM Rheinland_Staedte WHERE STADTNAME=stadt1;

      SELECT Noerdlicher_Grad,Noerdliche_Minute,oestlicher_Grad,oestliche_Minute INTO v_norgr1,v_nordmin1,v_ostgr1,v_ostmin1 FROM Rheinland_Staedte WHERE STADTNAME=stadt2;
      latitude_min:=v_norgr+v_nordmin/60;
      longitude_min:=v_ostgr+v_ostmin/60;
      latitude_min1:=v_norgr1+v_nordmin1/60;
      longitude_min1:=v_ostgr1+v_ostmin1/60;
      distance:= SQRT((latitude_min - latitude_min1)*(latitude_min - latitude_min1) + (longitude_min -longitude_min1)*(longitude_min -longitude_min1));
      return distance*60;
      END;
      END GEOGRAPHICAL_PACKAGE;
      /
```

Here is my table and Function what return Distance between two cities

Comment: Please edit your question and include the structure of your table and the call signature of your function. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you "know" that you need a cursor? This appears to be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - what is the problem you actually trying to solve rather than assuming the answer is a cursor?

Comment: I have a cities name with their latitude and longitude in degrees and minutes. I need to write a funktion with parameter of one city. what will return all distances to all other cities from the table. Is it not a work of cursor?

Comment: I can add if you need my funktion what return distance between 2 cities and also my table of cities.

Answer (score 1):

Use Oracle's [Spatial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b28004/xe_locator.htm#CIHFBGJG) Data:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Cities (
  id       NUMBER(8,0),
  name     VARCHAR2(25),
  location SDO_GEOMETRY
);

INSERT INTO Cities
          SELECT 1, 'London', SDO_GEOMETRY( 2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(-0.1278,51.5074,NULL), NULL, NULL) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'New York', SDO_GEOMETRY( 2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(-74.0059,40.7128,NULL), NULL, NULL) FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Hong Kong', SDO_GEOMETRY( 2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(114.1095,22.3964,NULL), NULL, NULL) FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA (
  TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DIMINFO, SRID
) VALUES (
  'CITIES',
  'LOCATION', 
  SDO_DIM_ARRAY(
    SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('LONG', -180.0, 180.0, 0.5), 
    SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('LAT', -90.0, 90.0, 0.5)
  ), 
  8307
);

CREATE INDEX CitiesTable_SIDX ON Cities( location ) INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT
  a.name,
  b.name,
  sdo_geom.sdo_distance( a.location, b.location, 0.005, 'unit=mile' ) distance
FROM cities a
     CROSS JOIN
     cities b
WHERE a.id < b.id
ORDER BY distance;
```

**Output**:

```
NAME                      NAME                        DISTANCE
------------------------- ------------------------- ----------
London                    New York                  3470.49915 
London                    Hong Kong                  5983.3067 
New York                  Hong Kong                 8057.67161
```

Answer (score 0):

It depeneds how you want to get output but you can return a cursor like this in your function. You should provide more information to better answer.

```
Cursor c1;
 Open c1 for 
select dist_func(city_param,city_id) from table_city ;
return c1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE  GEOGRAPHICAL_PACKAGE  AS
  FUNCTION Abstand(v_städteA Rheinlandstädte%rowtype,v_städteB      
  Rheinlandstädte%rowtype) RETURN NUMBER;
  TYPE ABSTANDSTABELLE IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);
  FUNCTION Entfernung(v_stadt  Rheinlandstädte%rowtype) RETURN   
  Abstandstabelle;

 END GEOGRAPHICAL_PACKAGE;
 /
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY GEOGRAPHICAL_PACKAGE AS 

 FUNCTION Abstand(v_städteA Rheinlandstädte%rowtype,v_städteB     
 Rheinlandstädte%rowtype) 
RETURN NUMBER IS

 abstand NUMBER;
 nordA NUMBER;
 nordB NUMBER; 
 ostA NUMBER;
 ostB NUMBER; 

BEGIN
nordA := v_städteA.MinuteN + v_städteA.GradN*60;
nordB := v_städteB.Minuten + v_städteB.GradN*60;
ostA :=  v_städteA.MinuteO + v_städteA.GradO*60;
ostB :=  v_städteB.MinuteO + v_städteB.GradO*60;

abstand := SQRT((POWER(nordA-nordB, 2)+POWER(ostA-ostB, 2))*1.850);

RETURN ROUND(abstand,0);
END Abstand;


FUNCTION Entfernung(v_stadt  Rheinlandstädte%rowtype) 
RETURN Abstandstabelle IS tabelle ABSTANDSTABELLE;

CURSOR c_städte IS
SELECT *
FROM Rheinlandstädte ;

v_andereStadt  Rheinlandstädte%rowtype;
v_entfernung NUMBER;

BEGIN

OPEN c_städte;

LOOP

  FETCH c_städte INTO v_andereStadt;
  v_entfernung := Abstand(v_stadt, v_andereStadt);
  tabelle(v_andereStadt.stadtname) := v_entfernung;
  EXIT WHEN c_städte%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
CLOSE c_städte;
RETURN tabelle;
END Entfernung;
```

And here is how to call it:

```
DECLARE
v_stadtname_a VARCHAR(20):='Düsseldorf';
v_stadtA Rheinlandstädte%rowtype;
v_stadtB Rheinlandstädte%rowtype;
abstand NUMBER;
tabelle GEOGRAPHICAL_PACKAGE.ABSTANDSTABELLE;
v_stadt Rheinlandstädte%rowtype; 
CURSOR c_sta IS
    SELECT * FROM Rheinlandstädte;
BEGIN 

SELECT * INTO v_stadtA
FROM rheinlandstädte
WHERE stadtname=v_stadtname_a;

OPEN c_sta;
LOOP
    FETCH c_sta INTO v_stadt;
    EXIT WHEN c_sta%NOTFOUND;
    tabelle := GEOGRAPHICAL_PACKAGE.Entfernung(v_stadtA);
   dbms_output.put_line('Abstand zwischen '||v_stadtA.stadtname||' und '||  
   v_stadt.stadtname||' beträgt: '||tabelle(v_stadt.stadtname)||' km.');   
END LOOP;
CLOSE c_sta;


END;
```